# Error:Unknown provider: AuditServiceProvider <- AuditService

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on `angular` project and I need to perform an audit. I have a web service to do insertion and to call that in my angular project, I have an audit service which will consume audit web service. The service itself works fine, it calls the web service and inserts the rows but when I'm trying to cover that service I'm experiencing the following issue

```
(function () {
 'use strict';

 angular
   .module('directContactInfo')
   .factory('auditService', ['$http', 'serviceResolver',
      auditServiceFactory
 ]);

 function auditServiceFactory(http, serviceResolver) {

return {
    performAudit: function (data, token) {
        var postData = angular.toJson(data, true);
        http({
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
            },
            url: 
      serviceResolver.auditWebservice.endpoints.post,
            data: postData
        });
       }
    }
  }
})();
```

And I'm trying to cover the above service using the following

```
'use strict';

 describe('Services: auditService', function () {

 beforeEach(module('directContactInfo'));

 beforeEach(inject(function ($httpBackend) {

 $httpBackend.whenGET('@@staticFilePath/customer-direct-contact-info- 
  search.html').respond(
   200, '');
}));

afterEach(inject(function ($httpBackend) {
   $httpBackend.flush();
   $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
   $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
}));

 it('should only make a post call with the correct endpoint and key', 
  inject(function ($httpBackend, auditService, serviceResolver) 
 {
  var accessToken = 'accessToken';
  var customerIdUpdate = 1234555;
  var customerDirectMessageAddressOldValue = "xyz@gmail.com";
  var customerDirectMessageAddressNewValue = "abc@gmail.com";
  var auditData = buildAccessAuditObj(customerIdUpdate, 
                       customerDirectMessageAddressOldValue,
                       customerDirectMessageAddressNewValue);
   var postData = angular.toJson(auditData, true);

 // We only expect a GET request with the supplied data to be triggered.


   $httpBackend.expectPOST(
    serviceResolver.auditWebservice.endpoints.post, postData, 
    {
   'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
   'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }, undefined).respond(function () {
    return [201,
   // jscs:disable
    {}
    // jscs:enable
 ];
});

   var criteria = {
       prvarAudApplId: '1234',
       prvarAuditActionId: '1234',
       userIdentification: '1234',
       profileName: 'ABCD',
       prvarProxyUserId: '0',
       prvarProxyProfileName: '',
       remoteAddress: '127.0.0.0',
       customerId: providerNpiUpdate,
      additionalDataText1: customerDirectMessageAddressOldValue ,
       additionalDataText2: customerDirectMessageAddressNewValue 
     };

// Make the call which relies on the mocked $httpBackend.
providerAccessAuditService.performAudit(criteria, accessToken);
 }));

function buildAccessAuditObj(selectedCustId, oldDirectMessageAddress, 
    newDirectMessageAddress) {
    return {
      prvarAudApplId: '1234',
   prvarAuditActionId: '1234',
   userIdentification: '1234',
   profileName: 'ABCD',
   prvarProxyUserId: '0',
   prvarProxyProfileName: '',
   remoteAddress: '127.0.0.0',
    customerNpi: selectedCustId,
   additionalDataText1: oldDirectMessageAddress,
    additionalDataText2: newDirectMessageAddress
 };
}
});
```

And the exception its throwing is that

```
   Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: AuditServiceProvider 
                 <- auditService
     https://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.2/$injector/unpr? 
   p0=auditServiceProvider%20%3C-%20auditService
  at bower_components/angular/angular.js:138:12
  at bower_components/angular/angular.js:4891:19
  at Object.getService [as get] (bower_components/angular/angular.js:5051:32)
  at bower_components/angular/angular.js:4896:45
  at getService (bower_components/angular/angular.js:5051:32)
  at injectionArgs (bower_components/angular/angular.js:5076:58)
  at Object.invoke (bower_components/angular/angular.js:5100:18)
  at Object.WorkFn (bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3264:20)
   Error: Declaration Location
   at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (bower_components/angular- 
  mocks/angular-mocks.js:3227:25)
  at Suite.<anonymous> (app/services/auditService.spec.js:18:72)
   at app/services/auditService.spec.js:3:1
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your karma.conf.js loads the script that defines the service you are trying to inject also make sure your module has the module that the service is defined in as a dependency (basically angular 1.x has one injector for the lifetime of the app that is used for getting instances to inject from any modules or their dependent modules).